# WordPress > HTML/PHP/JS > change text of footer on a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'll try and be as clear as possible.
Info:
- WordPress Website

The website has 2 Languages Hebrew & English. The problem lies in the Footer.
I have 4 lines that will say:
- Address: ........
- Phone: .......
- Fax: ......
- Email: ........@...com

Now this is all written in Hebrew and I want to change these into English when someone is looking on the English page.
In short, a way to target the Page ID (let's say the page ID is 20 for the English main page and 30 for the Contact Us page) I want to target those Pages Footer and change those specific lines to a different one. I am also using ACF Pro.

In theory it will function like this:
       If Page ID is = to 20 & 30 change  text in the footer.

I can give the h4 and ID if that will help. As for the ACF I can just make new ones and call them address_en and have the address in English. Of course if there is a better way please let me know.

I have no idea how to go about this.

```css
/* Some CSS not relavent */
```

```html
 <footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        // Some Code here not relavent
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>כתובת: <?php the_field('address', 24); ?></h4>
        <h4>טלפון: <?php the_field('telephone', 24); ?></h4>
        <h4 >פקס:00-000-0000</h4>
        <h4>כתובת אימייל: <?php the_field('emailaddress', 24); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
          // Something here not relavent
    </div>
        
   </div>
  </div><!-- container -->

 </footer>
```

Have a great day.

Comment: Does your entire site have the same footer content on every page except 20 and 30?

Comment: The site is small maybe 6 pages in hebrew and 2 in english might expand the english to 3-4 pages in the future. And yes the footer is the same for the entire site same for the header. I simply changed the position of certain icons to ltr or rtl depending on weather the page is english or hebrew. the Front page is in hebrew I then created a new page (ID 20) and translated it into english. But the footer is in Hebrew hence the problem.

Comment: The question is: what plugin are you using to make your site multilingual? Putting fixed post IDs in the code is really ugly. For example, if you're using Polylang, each translation has their own ACF fields, so you can easily edit them in the English or Hebrew version of the page. Also, Polylang offers string translations which can be used for global label translations into the selected languages. You might want to consider a more future-proof solution for a multilingual site.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on page id's since pages can be replaced etc. If you only have a few pages in English, you could simply add a category called "english" on those pages. When the page is then rendered (in the page template) and it has the category "english", load the English footer instead of the default footer. Another alternative could be to add an ACF field with a drop down called "Footer" where you can define which footer it has. If it's default to hebrew, you only need to set it on the English pages. Then you would do it the same way as for categories.

Comment: The site uses no plugin for translation. I am working on this site after the previous developer stopped around 2 years ago. It already has content on it and a few stuff in it like donations. Moving to something like Polylang is gonna be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `the_field('address', 24);` you're getting the ACF field from the post with the ID 24. That may not be what you want to do in a global element like a footer. ACF has an [options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) element which might be better suited for setting something like that.

If you went that route, you're if/then statement would be something like this.

```
<?php 
  if (get_the_ID() != 20 || get_the_ID() != 30){
      the_field('address', 'option');
    } else {
      the_field('address_en', 'option');
    }
;?>
```